# JPA 2.0 with Glassfish 2.1

Tags: hibernate, glassfish, jpa-2.0

Just wanted to find out if its possible to use JPA 2.0 with Glassfish 2.1?
Has someone tried it before?

I will be using the latest hibernate implementation of JPA 2.0 as the provider. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840880/upgrade-glassfish-v2-to-jpa-2-0

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used JPA 2.0 in glassfish 2.1 but I have used JPA 1.0 (toplink) with Glassfish 3

All I needed to do is include the toplink library to the project and use it in the persistence.xml

You can try to include the JPA2.0 library into your project, set your persistence.xml provider (for example `<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>`) and deploy it to glassfish 2.1. It should work.